# Pinch zoom of an external usb touchpad cannot be disabled on Firefox

Tags: usb, firefox, touchpad, multi-touch

I have an external usb touchpad connected to a laptop. I want to remove the pinch zoom gesture while I am on Mozilla Firefox.

Inside `about:config`, I set `apz.gtk.touchpad_pinch.enabled` `False`; after that I restarted.

However **I am still able to pinch zooming with my touchpad**.
I believe there is something non-trivial in the input recognition, in fact `xinput` gives the following output:

```
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
        ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
        ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

which doesn't provide any info about my touchpad.

Is there a way to disable pinch zoom in the browser without dealing with ubuntu inputs settigs? Or do we have to change several settings from Xwayland or libinput?

Specs: My machine is a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming with Ubuntu 22.04. The touchpad is a perixx PERIPAD-504.